# Git: How can I cleanly depend on a PR that hasn't merged?

Tags: git, workflow

The goal is to keep the workflow efficient and the history clean.

**A common problem**

I have several smallish features I want to introduce that will depend on each other, and I don't want to be blocked on a 2nd PR waiting for the 1st to merge (I do want it to be in a separate branch).

To clarify, I have 2(+)  features I need to add: `feature-1` and `feature-2`. `feature-2` depends on `feature-1`. These will both live on different branches, and it may take several days for a PR of `feature-1` to be accepted. I would like to work on `feature-2`, a separate branch, while waiting, and in the mean time `feature-1` may have some required changes that should percolate to `feature-2`.

**3 solutions**:

- I could branch `feature-2` off of `feature-1`
- I could make a new branch "`several-features`" and merge branches into there before they make  it into `master`.
- I could branch off a local `master` into which I optimistically merge `feature-1`, and merge back into `feature-2` any time I need to propagate a change from `-1`.

**My current solution** is the latter:

1. create a branch `feature-1` from `master`
2. write code, push it, and start the PR
3. merge it locally to `master` while waiting for it to merge
4. branch from that a `feature-2` (now this depends on `feature-1`)
5. if changes are requested on `feature-1`, fix them, optimistically merge back into `master`, merge back into `feature-2`, and do this any time `feature-1` has something that `feature-2` needs, IE, always flowing through a local(-only) version of master.

I don't like that my master will have had a different history than the official one, but since git is like an append-only (mostly) vcs, and I think commits are an associative operation... will their histories actually be the same?

Comment: Can you clarify why you chose solution 3 over solution 1 or solution 2? In your situation I would likely chose solution 1 (both for `merge` and `rebase`)

Comment: @Vlad274 Good question, no real reason. regarding these responses, I've been trying solution 1 on a recent set of features and prefer it to 3. I use `merge` instead of `rebase` and I really don't see why @eftshift0's answer would be prefered (besides rewriting a "cleaner" hx, to which I'm aesthetically opposed).

Answer (score 2):

I wish I understood the question.... but I will explain how to work on this work-flow kind-of-easily.

If you start feat2 from feat1, as you work on feat2 you might encounder some scenarios:

Scenario 1:
   feat1 got some additional revivions.... piece of cake:

```
git rebase feat1
```

Scenario 2:
    feat1 got *moved* (rebased, probably). This is a little more involved. We are not even sure that the revisions of feat1 were rebased without conflicts, all we now is that the branch was *moved* and we don't know anything else (the developer might have decided to start over, and so the original revisions have no relation to the new ones):

```
git rebase --onto feat1 old-tip-of-feat1 feat2 # ask git to move feat2 discarding all old revisions of feat1, and put them on top of feat1
```

Actually it doesn't have to be the old tip of the branch, it could be the last revision of feat1 that is in the history of feat2.

Scenario 3:
    feat1 gets merge into master. This is simple:

```
git rebase master
```

Those are the basics.

Comment: I never use `rebase`  on shared projects, but I guess you are suggesting that it's safe as  long as work never gets pushed up before rebasing? What if I `feature-1` and `-2` need to be publicly shared, and `rebase`ing is then harmful? Do you see a problem with my solution? (Oh, and I added a paragraph to be more explicit, beginning: "To clarify, I have 2...")

Comment: @Josh.F How is rebasing inherently harmful- even on shared projects? if you know what you're doing it should be fine.

Comment: Rebase is not harmful per-se. It's just a tool that is available in the toolbox. As long as you know the technique to use it, you will be fine.

Comment: The problem that I see is that you are keeping _your_ local master separate from the upstream master... and **that** can be a major source of confusion (not te say headaches). Consider not having to see yourself tied to using your local master and that might help you see/understand what has to be done.

Comment: I guess there are 2 questions now: 1) is rebase harmful on shared projects, 2) is rebase the right solution for using a PR before it's merged. Re #1, I guess it's preference, but I don't  ever rebase any work that someone else even _might_ have. My big question is #2, is rebase the right tool for using a PR that hasn't been merged. Frankly, I don't like rewriting history, and IME anything you can do with rebase can be done less destructively through other means (it does have it's place tho, for sure).

Comment: 1 - No 2 - It depends. Say.... you are in charge of a feature... and you submit your changes for review... and you get some reviews that you will have to correct and the base branch moved (even more importantly... it moved and the code is involved in _your_ feature branch). Given that the feature branch is yours and no one cares about it until it is merged into the upstream branch (even if it's public).... **why wouldn't you rebase?** Merging is not the right approach if you want to provide a clean history for your feature (say... so that it can be easily moved around/backported as needed).

Comment: I see the logic, and perhaps my views on `rebase` are biased because I've tried to not use it. I'd still like to see others weigh in, so I i'm going to just upvote for now, and spend some time reconsidering `rebase`, thanks :)